# Efficiently replacing in a python triple-nested list

Tags: python, algorithm, performance

I have a list of twitter data containing words and associated part of speech tags, such as:

```
[  
   [  
      [  
         'word1.1',
         'tag1.1'
      ],
      [  
         'word1.2',
         'tag1.2'
      ]
   ],
   [  
      [  
         'word2.1',
         'tag2.1'
      ],
      [  
         'word2.2',
         'tag2.2'
      ]
   ]
]
```

where `word1.1` is the first word of the first tweet, `tag1.1` is its associated tag, etc. I want to replace, in all tweets, all words that occur less than a threshold (say 2) times with an unknown word token `<unknown>`.

I'm using `collections.Counter` to quickly get a list of the words that appear less than this threshold of times, but I'm looking for a way to quickly replace words that appear less than this threshold of times. What I'm doing at the moment is getting all words to replace, and looping through every word of every tweet, checking if the word is in the list of words to replace and replacing it if so. This is extremely expensive, however; is there a better way to do this?

If I set the threshold for replacing to 2 (aka replacing all singletons), there are 97956 words to replace. I'm not sure how many words are in the total set, but there are 50,000 tweets.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't indicate whether you are including the tag as part of the word identities. That is, if a word is tagged in different ways ("play" can be a noun or a verb, e.g.) does that count as one occurrence or two?

Answer (score 0):

A way to make this a lot faster is to make the `list` of things to remove a `set`

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do it with json, for example:

```
import json
a = [
    [
        [
            'word1.1',
            'tag1.1',
        ]
    ],
]
b = json.dumps(a)
b = b.replace('"word1.1"', '"<unknown>"')
a = json.loads(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I'd suggest consolidating the words into groups of common items with multiple references. Consider this:

```
tweets = [
    [ ['hello'], ['how'], ['are'], ['you?'], ],
    [ ['hello'], ['i'], ['am'], ['fine'] ],
]
```

You can consolidate them thusly:

```
one_true_hello = tweets[0][0]

tweets[1][0] = one_true_hello
```

At this point, both the first tweet and the second tweet actually refer to the same `['hello']` list. (This is a common source of confusion in pass-by-reference/pass-by-value questions.) So if you make a change to the `one_true_hello` list, it will appear in both places.

If you can perform that consolidation while doing your counting (possibly by making the count the third element of the list, after word and tag?) you can then convert your O(n) problem (n=number of words used) into an O(m) problem (m = distinct words used) and do the replacement in a single pass (just reset 'hello' -> '' when count < 2).